# Active Reports 2: Why my report does not appear in run-time?

Tags: vb6, activereports

I have a VB6.0 legacy project which uses Active Reports Pro 2.0 for reports.
In run-time, every thing seems to be all right but the report does not appear.

I use windows 7 as my O/s.

What 's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific. Exactly what line of code are you running to show the report that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your report code with error handling and log these.  Specifically, hit up the Detail, ReportStart, ReportInitialize events.  Mostly likely the problem is occuring somewhere in those and either your code or ActiveReports is eating the error.